# How can I pause an Intent in iOS to run ? ( iOS Shortcut Automation )

Tags: ios, swift, shortcut

I want to "pause" an Intent ( iOS Shortcut Automation ) how can I achieve it?
Basically we have a small task to execute, whenever we setup an automation for one app, lets say LinkedIn, our app runs and asks the user whether they still want to continue with LinkedIn or whether they don't want to.

The automation to open our app when LinkedIn is opened is working fine. What we want to achieve is that once a user taps on "Continue to LinkedIn" it should "pause" the automation this time and open LinkedIn instead of opening our app again.

Basically, open the intent conditionally, without user interaction

Comment: Removed tag `android-intent`

Comment: Do you "know" when the user logs in with LinkedIn?

Comment: That is not the concern, it should just open the LinkedIn app once I tap on "Continue to LinkedIn" it can be any other app than LinkedIn

Comment: It matters because if you know what will trigger "resume" you can create a plan. But since you know better have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XCTests then you can consider the following code,

```
while XCUIApplication().state == .runningBackground {
    sleep(1) //Here you can specify for how much time you want to pause the automation
}
```

You can refer to the [XCUIApplication.State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/state)

Comment: I will check this and mark as acceptance if this works, thank you.

Comment: Sure, @OmkarJadhav. Let me know if it worked or helped you in any other way.

Comment: Sorry, Pratik, apparently it did not work, we are look for a solution somewhat similar to https://apps.apple.com/app/one-sec-screen-time-focus/id1532875441 this app.

Our requirement is different though